# Illicit mix of collations in MySQL when inserting unicode to database

Tags: mysql, django, unicode

I'm running into this error when inserting lines containing unicode characters during django tests:

```
InternalError: (1267, u"Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

Culprit:

```
نعليقات و
```

Now then I did some research and it was suggested for me to do:

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

I followed this example and did this instead in django:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(row)
cursor.execute(
    'ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 '
    'COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;')
for row in results:
    cursor.execute(
        'ALTER TABLE %s CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 '
        'COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;' % (row[0]))
```

Note: The reason why I need it to be mb4 is because I need to support emojis:

```
Happy Birthday! タクミ！
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, utf8mb4 is necessary.

But the error relates to `latin1`.  This *probably* indicates that the *connection* is not set to utf8.

My paultry notes suggest that Django configuration has some charset and use_unicode options.  Please show us what you have there, especially if that provides the solution.

Comment: I have this: 'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},